# Aggregate classes to one single class

Tags: java, android

is it possible to copy the following class:

```
public class StoryEntity {
    FeedEntity feeds;
    ImageEntity images ;
    VideoEntity videos;

// setters & getters
}
```

to:

```
public class Story {
    List<String> feeds;
    List<String> images ;
    List<String> videos;

  //  setters & getters
}
```

image entity class is :

```
public class ImageEntity {
    String oUrl;
    String url;
    String thumb;
    String title;
    String alt;
    int count;

    public ImageEntity() {
    }
 // setters and getters
}
```

other entity classes are similar to ImageEntity class i.e. contains fields of string and int data types.
Thanks for your help

Comment: What do you mean by "how to map" fields like .... to a assraylist of type string like .... ??

Comment: i mean is it possible to map images filed of type ImageEntity to ArrayList<String>

Comment: You are still not very clear on what you want but I think you are looking for making a list of `ImageEntity` then you can do `ArrayList<ImageEntity>` .. This would prepare a list of `ImageEntity` "objects", which you can traverse to get desired `ImageEntity` "object" etc.

Comment: i am sorry for ambiguity. but i want to copy a class `ImageEntity` to list of string

Comment: You cannot copy a class to a string. But you can capture the state of an object (runtime representation of class) and concert it into string, then you can add it in a list of string. This is what you want ?? It would be much easy to understand your problem if you can give some example on what you want to do. If you are planning to give example, then please edit your question.

Comment: thanks for your attempts to help me. i have edited my question to be more specific

Comment: Can you update the question with the contents of one of your Entity classes? Why do you need a separate Entity class at all if they are just lists of objects?

Comment: Okay, now why can't you do `List<ImageEntity> images` in Story?

Comment: in fact i thought it would be good idea to combine the entity classes into one class instead of keep creating the same entity classes in my app modules. i don't know if this idea is applicable or not